# What is use of "group_by_no_leaf"?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

We are passing "group_by_no_leaf" in context of action, can anyone help me to understand exact use of that?

For example, as given below :

```
<record id="action_project_task_user_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Tasks Analysis</field>
            <field name="res_model">report.project.task.user</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">graph,pivot</field>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_task_project_user_search"/>
            <field name="context">{'group_by_no_leaf':1,'group_by':[]}</field>
            <field name="help">This report allows you to analyse the performance of your projects and users. You can analyse the quantities of tasks, the hours spent compared to the planned hours, the average number of days to open or close a task, etc.</field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

"group_by_no_leaf" is an optional parameter for list views that hides the top row of buttons when given. (The row containing the 'Create', 'Import', etc. buttons).

Source: /addons/web/static/tests/views/list_tests.js line 1569 contains the unit_test to validate this behaviour.